# How to create Proxy server app for other devices

Tags: android

I am going to make a Proxy Server app like [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.proxyserver)[1]. I have tried many things to create wifi proxy for other phone.

I am using this code.Please give me suggestion or link to make proxy server from my app.

```
public void setWifiProxySettings5() {
      WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)   getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      WifiConfiguration config = GetCurrentWifiConfiguration(manager);
      if (null == config)
        return;

      try {
        //linkProperties is no longer in WifiConfiguration
        Class proxyInfoClass = Class.forName("android.net.ProxyInfo");
        Class[] setHttpProxyParams = new Class[1];
        setHttpProxyParams[0] = proxyInfoClass;
        Class wifiConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration");
        Method setHttpProxy = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setHttpProxy", setHttpProxyParams);
        setHttpProxy.setAccessible(true);

        //Method 1 to get the ENUM ProxySettings in IpConfiguration
        Class ipConfigClass = Class.forName("android.net.IpConfiguration");
        Field f = ipConfigClass.getField("proxySettings");
        Class proxySettingsClass = f.getType();

        //Method 2 to get the ENUM ProxySettings in IpConfiguration
        //Note the $ between the class and ENUM
        //Class proxySettingsClass = Class.forName("android.net.IpConfiguration$ProxySettings");

        Class[] setProxySettingsParams = new Class[1];
        setProxySettingsParams[0] = proxySettingsClass;
        Method setProxySettings = wifiConfigClass.getDeclaredMethod("setProxySettings", setProxySettingsParams);
        setProxySettings.setAccessible(true);


        ProxyInfo pi = ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy("192.168.1.4", 8118);
        //Android 5 supports a PAC file
        //ENUM value is "PAC"
        //ProxyInfo pacInfo = ProxyInfo.buildPacProxy(Uri.parse("http://localhost/pac"));

        //pass the new object to setHttpProxy
        Object[] params_SetHttpProxy = new Object[1];
        params_SetHttpProxy[0] = pi;
        setHttpProxy.invoke(config, params_SetHttpProxy);

        //pass the enum to setProxySettings
        Object[] params_setProxySettings = new Object[1];
        params_setProxySettings[0] = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) proxySettingsClass, "STATIC");
        setProxySettings.invoke(config, params_setProxySettings);

        //save the settings
        manager.updateNetwork(config);
        manager.disconnect();
        manager.reconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("wifiProxy", e.toString());
    }
}

WifiConfiguration GetCurrentWifiConfiguration(WifiManager manager) {
    if (!manager.isWifiEnabled())
        return null;

    List<WifiConfiguration> configurationList = manager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    WifiConfiguration configuration = null;
    int cur = manager.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
    for (int i = 0; i < configurationList.size(); ++i) {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = configurationList.get(i);
        if (wifiConfiguration.networkId == cur)
            configuration = wifiConfiguration;
    }

    return configuration;
}
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear. What's the problem/question? What isn't working? What do you need help with?

Comment: i am trying like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.proxyserver        @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: both client and server are connected logs are shown but Internet is not working on the other device from where i bypass proxy @SamiKuhmonen